TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'reminder.map')
this is my reminder-list.tsx, how many time i tricked it, i always fail to do that, how to fix it
i always got the TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'reminder.map') error
import { ReminderDetails } from "@/types/types";
import React from "react";

interface ReminderListProps {
  reminder: ReminderDetails[];
}

const ComponentReminderList: React.FC<ReminderListProps> = ({ reminder }) => {
  return (
    <tbody>
      {reminder.map((item, index) => (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td className="text-[hsl(210,17%,98%)] w-[20%] font-light text-xs px-4 py-4">
            {item.patient}
          </td>
          <td className="text-[hsl(210,17%,98%)] w-[20%] font-light text-xs px-4 py-4">
            {item.medicine}
          </td>
          <td className="text-[hsl(210,17%,98%)] w-[20%] font-light text-xs px-4 py-4">
            {item.dosage} - {item.dosage_unit}
          </td>
          <td className="text-[hsl(210,17%,98%)] w-[20%] font-light text-xs px-4 py-4">
            {item.schedule}
          </td>
          <td className="text-[hsl(210,17%,98%)] w-[20%] font-light text-xs px-4 py-4">
            {item.notes}
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  );
};

export default ComponentReminderList;


The error just tells you that reminder is undefined so there is no map function on it. You'll need to show us how ComponentReminderList is used in your code. It is either not passing the reminder prop or is passing it something that is undefined.

@BrianThompson i think i found the answer, thanks a lot for the time to reply sir:)

The error says in other words that you can't read properties of undefined.
the reminder prop is somehow undefined and passed as undefined in the parent component. you should check where you used your ComponentReminderList component and check the props you passed.
Edit: I removed the early check of props because they will never be undefined since they are not optional in props interface

This is not a best practice. The interface does not declare reminder as optional, so it should never be undefined, meaning the bug is at a higher level, not here. At the very least the interface should be updated, but most likely this will just hide the error for the OP who expects reminder to be passed.

You're right I didn't check the interface.

issokay sir, but thanks for the suggestions, finally, i found the answer by checking again my code:)
